# One node in hadoop cluster failure

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I have configured 10 nodes HDP hadoop cluster recently, each node is of  OS SLES11..

On master node I have configured all master services and clients..also the mabari-server.  Remaining nodes other slave services and their clients.

NTP sync is on, other pre-requisites also fine.

I am experiencing weird behavior on hadoop cluster, After starting all the services within few hours one of the node goes down.

When I experienced this first time, I have restarted that particular node and added back to the cluster. 
Now My master node is causing the same issue due to which whole cluster is down. I have checked the logs but there are no indications related to failure. 
I am clueless what is the root cause for the failure of the node in hadoop cluster?

Below are logs :-
the system which went down:
**/var/log/messages**

> these are /var/log/messages: notice)=0', processed='source(src)=6830'
>   Apr 23 05:22:43 lnx1863 SuSEfirewall2: SuSEfirewall2 not active Apr 23
>   05:23:49 lnx1863 SuSEfirewall2: SuSEfirewall2 not active Apr 23
>   05:24:17 lnx1863 sudo:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ;
>   COMMAND=/usr/bin/du -h / Apr 23 05:24:55 lnx1863 SuSEfirewall2:
>   SuSEfirewall2 not active Apr 23 05:25:22 lnx1863 kernel:
>   [248531.127254] megasas: Found FW in FAULT state, will reset adapter.
>   Apr 23 05:25:22 lnx1863 kernel: [248531.127260] megaraid_sas:
>   resetting fusion adapter. Apr 23 05:25:22 lnx1863 kernel:
>   [248531.127427] megaraid_sas: Reset not supported, killing adapter.

**namenode logs:-**

> INFO 2015-04-23 05:27:43,665 Heartbeat.py:78 - Building Heartbeat:
>   {responseId = 7607, timestamp = 1429781263665, commandsInProgress =
>   False, componentsMapped = True} INFO 2015-04-23 05:28:44,053
>   security.py:135 - Encountered communication error. Details:
>   SSLError('The read operation timed out',) ERROR 2015-04-23
>   05:28:44,053 Controller.py:278 - Connection to http://localhost was
>   lost (details=Request to
>   https://localhost:8441/agent/v1/heartbeat/localhostip failed due to
>   Error occured during connecting to the server: The read operation
>   timed out) INFO 2015-04-23 05:29:16,061 NetUtil.py:48 - Connecting to
>   https://localhost:8440/connection_info INFO 2015-04-23 05:29:16,118
>   security.py:93 - SSL Connect being called.. connecting to the server

Comment: Post namenode logs when your namenode stopped. Post other logs too if possible.

Comment: I will update in my question.

Comment: `After starting all the services within few hours one of the node goes down`. Which node went down first? Can you post the logs for that node's hadoop processes?

Comment: Master node goes down, and I have posted logs in the question it self, those logs are for the same node.

Comment: Do these in terminal: `sudo mkdir -p $HADOOP_HOME/logs-backup`, `mv $HADOOP_HOME/logs/*.log $HADOOP_HOME/logs-backup`. Now start hadoop processes. Post the complete namenode log instead of just part of it.